# Segmentation fault al imprimir un array en C++

Tags: c++, array, punteros

estoy teniendo problemas al imprimir un array en C++. Si hago lo que indico en el código de abajo, se puede acceder a los datos de cada objeto en el array, por lo tanto imprime:

```
void testGetVehiculos(){
    string ci = "c11";
    int cantVehiculos=2;

    int pos = buscarSocio(ci); //devuelve la posición del socio con documento ci en un array global
    vector<DtVehiculo*> vehiculos = socios[pos]->getVehiculos(ci, cantVehiculos);

    DtVehiculo** vehiculos = vehiculos.data();//obtenerVehiculos(ci, cantVehiculos);
    string marca = "";  
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Se encontraron: " << cantVehiculos << " vehiculos.\n";
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Listado: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cantVehiculos ; i++){
            //DtVehiculo  m = vehiculos[i];
    //        DtVehiculo* c = cons[i];
            marca = vehiculos[i]->getMarca(); 
            cout << " \n";
            cout << "------------------ \n";
            cout << "-> Número de vehiculo: " << i<< "\n";
            cout << "-> Marca: " << marca << "\n";
            cout << "------------------ \n";

    }

    cout << "-------FIN-----\n";
}
```

Si pongo en una función a parte (que es lo que se pide hacer), al llegar a la línea:

```
marca = vehiculos[i]->getMarca();
```

Me da Segmentation Fault. Aquí el código completo que da problemas:

```
DtVehiculo** obtenerVehiculos(string ci, int& maxVehiculos){
    int pos = buscarSocio(ci); //devuelve la posición del socio con documento ci en un array global
    vector<DtVehiculo*> vehiculos = socios[pos]->getVehiculos(ci, maxVehiculos);// obtiene la lista de Vehiculos de la clase Socio. Hasta acá  parece funcionar todo bien
    return vehiculos.data();
};


void testGetVehiculos()
{
    string ci = "c11";
    int cantVehiculos=2;

    DtVehiculo** vehiculos = obtenerVehiculos(ci, cantVehiculos);
    string marca = "";  
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Se encontraron: " << cantVehiculos << " vehiculos.\n";
    cout << " \n";
    cout << "Listado: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cantVehiculos ; i++){
            //DtVehiculo  m = vehiculos[i];
    //        DtVehiculo* c = cons[i];
            marca = vehiculos[i]->getMarca(); 
            cout << " \n";
            cout << "------------------ \n";
            cout << "-> Número de vehiculo: " << i<< "\n";
            cout << "-> Marca: " << marca << "\n";
            cout << "------------------ \n";

    }

    cout << "-------FIN-----\n";
}
```

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Ese no es el código completo que da problemas, no vemos ni dónde se define `socios` ni dónde se rellena `socios` ni la definición de la función `buscarSocio`; por favor: añade el código que falta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observemos tu función *problemática*:

```
int pos = buscarSocio(ci); //devuelve la posición del socio con documento ci en un array global
```

Vale, eso aparenta estar bien. Sigamos:

```
vector<DtVehiculo*> vehiculos = socios[pos]->getVehiculos(ci, maxVehiculos);// obtiene la lista de Vehiculos de la clase Socio. Hasta acá  parece funcionar todo bien
```

Aquí ya hay cosas raras: creas una variable **automática** (o, lo que es lo mismo, **temporal**).

```
return vehiculos.data( );
```

Y aquí se confima: devuelves un dato contenido en la variable **temporal** anterior.

En teoría, no debería de haber problemas ... hasta que nos documentamos sobre lo que hace la función [`std::vector< >::data( )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data):

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a valid range, even if the container is empty (data() is not dereferenceable in that case).

Vale. El valor devuelto por `data( )` apunta a la memoria interna del `std::vector` ... que recordemos era automático. ¿ Que pasará con esa memoria, cuando el vector se destruya ? Efectivamente, que la memoria se libera ... y el valor obtenido previamente al llamar a `data( )` **deja de ser válido**.

Una posible solución sería devolver directamente el `std::vector< >`:

```
std::vector< DtVehiculo * > obtenerVehiculos( string ci, int & maxVehiculos ) {
  int pos = buscarSocio( ci );
  return socios[pos]->getVehiculos( ci, maxVehiculos );
};
```

Y un cambio mínimo dentro de tu `testGetVehiculos( )`:

```
auto vehiculos = obtenerVehiculos( ci, cantVehiculos );
```

Con eso, deberia de funcionar.